# Trying to eval back repr(CookieJar)

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookielib

I am trying to deserialize a `cookielib.CookieJar.__repr__()` output back to a CookieJar object.  I did:

```
cjs = repr(myCJ)
cj = eval(cjs)
```

It gave a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.  The `cjs` string is more than 3,000 characters long,  The second statement above gave the following actual output:

```
>>> cjx=eval(cjs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    <cookielib.CookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='AMAuthCookie', value=' ....
...........lots deleted....and next is the actual last line...
comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I suspect that the ^ character is pointing to the very first character of the repr string, where the first few characters are:

```
>>> cjs[:50]
"<cookielib.CookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='AMAut"
```

May I know whether there is something fundamentally wrong with what I am doing before I investigate if the `repr` function is giving issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repr` is not guaranteed to be `eval`able. You should serialize the object via `pickle` instead, which is designed for object serialization and deserialization. Like so:

```
import cPickle
cjs = cPickle.dumps(myCJ)
cj = cPickle.loads(cjs)
```

---

In this case, the representation that `CookieJar` gives back is not remotely valid Python syntax. If you *absolutely have to* deal with this syntax, you may try

```
cookielist = eval(cjs[ len('<cookielib.CookieJar') : -len('>') ])
```

to extract out the list of cookies, then create a CookieJar from it. But I cannot guarantee that this would work.

Comment: Thanks.  With cPickle, I get a `TypeError: can't pickle lock objects`

Comment: You can try pickling the cookies inside the cookiejar instead: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18169748/1204143

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did. Took some effort, but it works.  Round trip str() compare matches perfectly.